# Migration from Lexware Vereinsverwaltung to CiviCRM

Tags: migration

Has anybody moved from the Windows-based [Lexware Vereinsverwaltung](https://www.lexware-vereinsverwaltung.de) application to CiviCRM?

Might there be features, which CiviCRM is missing?
How can I best migrate the data from that application into CiviCRM?

*As "Lexware Vereinsverwaltung" is probably an application with limited reach only used in Germany, I don't expect somebody has experience migrating from it to CiviCRM (surprise me!). But I will use this question to record my learnings from looking into it myself.*

*I decided to open a separate question to ask about [general considerations for moving to CiviCRM](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/14818/when-switching-to-civicrm-from-another-system-what-do-i-need-to-consider).*

Answer (score 1):

You could also check with Systopia, who are CiviCRM partners based in Germany: https://systopia.de/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like these folks have some relevant experience - see https://sfe-ev.org/?page=1