# When switching to CiviCRM from another system, what do I need to consider?

Tags: evaluating-civicrm

We are currently using a different software for managing members, fees and donations and now considering to move to CiviCRM because it is easier to for multiple people to work on the data.

What are general things we should consider before switching to CiviCRM?

What are important steps or best practices for a migration from a different system to CiviCRM?

Answer (score 5):

## Migrating Existing Data

Migrating data (and processes) from a previously used (CRM) system is not a routine task. It will probably involve discussions, how existing workflows can be represented in CiviCRM - or what might even be changed.

Data can be imported into CiviCRM in the csv format. There is a field for "External Identifier" in the CiviCRM database that can save the connection to the identifiers of records in the old system.

## General Aspects to Consider

There are a number of different aspects to consider. The [CiviCRM User Guide](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/) actual provides a lot of good information about this.

### Cost

see [What is the price of CiviCRM?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9666/what-is-the-price-of-civicrm)

CiviCRM is open-source and therefore itself available for free but you will need to pay hosting it on a server. Also, if you're not a techie you may need to pay for an expert for installation and support.

### Hosting

see [CiviCRM User Guide: Hosting](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/getting-prepared/hosting/)

If you take care of administering the system yourself on a webserver it will be cheap. If you lack the technical expertise and need a stable system, consider getting a complete hosted CiviCRM system from a provider.

### Change Management

see [CiviCRM User Guide: Transitioning to CiviCRM](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/getting-prepared/transitioning-to-civicrm/)

Don't forget to get the people from your organisation on board with your plans.